# responsive website with positioning of pictures

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to build a responsive website using javascript and css, but I don't understand how because I am a new programmer.

This is what the website should look like:

[image]

I have 9 pictures, and I want to display them as follows:

- The header picture will always be 100% of the original browser width no matter if the window is resized.
- The two logo pictures should always be in their positions even if the window is resized.
- 6 of the pictures have to be arranged in 2 lines in such a way that if the window is resized, you will always see all the pictures fit to the window width and height.

This is what I have done till now, but it doesn't give the result I wanted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
        </style>

        <div style="position:relative">
            <img src="header.png" style="width:100%; position:absolute;">
            <img src="logo1.png" style="left:30px; position:absolute;">
            <img src="logo2.png" alt="" style="right:30px; position:absolute;">
        </div>

        <img src="1.jpg" style="position:relative; top:100px;">
        <img src="2.jpg" style="position:relative; left:30px;">
        <img src="3.jpg" style="position:relative; left:30px;">
        <br>
        <img src="4.jpg" style="position:relative; left:30px;">
        <img src="5.jpg" style="position:relative; left:30px;">
        <img src="6.jpg" style="position:relative;left:30px;">
    </body>
</html>
```

How should I do this with Javascript code (using `window.resize`) and CSS positioning?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: first of all, you should avoid using inline styles.

Comment: Do you expect us to do your work? At least post what you have tried so far, so that we can orient you better on what to do and what not to do. Responsive design, whilst it being a simple concept, it is not learned, and much less, applied in just one day of reading and investigating.

Comment: Please don't "tag-spam".  [tag:jquery] has nothing to do with this since you don't mention it in your OP.

Comment: You should start by learning basics html & css. It's not to blame you, but you have to start from the beginning, you can't jump in responsive design etc.. if you don't know how to do positionning in html & css.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try and check the frameworks: 
[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/),
[Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
They both have explanations for deeper investigation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Mzf hopefully, frameworks like Bootstrap should not be down until a couple of years.

Comment: @Mzf - the essential part of the answer is the name of the solution, that the name is presented as a link is an added, non-essential bonus, hence the answer does stand on its own.